# How to properly display checkbox form controls in ASP.NET Core Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a model with a boolean property which will be shown as a checkbox in my view:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And I am creating the view like this:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input asp-for="TestProperty" value="true" class="form-check-input" />
    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="TestProperty"></label>
</div>
```

Below is the HTML output in the browser:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input value="true" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TestProperty field is required." id="TestProperty" name="TestProperty">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="TestProperty">TestProperty</label>
</div>
```

And I can see below hidden element is appended at the end of the form:

```
<input name="TestProperty" type="hidden" value="false">
```

When I submit the form this is the request body:

```
TestProperty: true
TestProperty: false
```

The value in the first line is the value in the check box element and the second line is the value of the hidden element that overrides the first line value when received in the controller. I noticed that when I click on the checkbox the hidden input's value does not change.

The first solution that comes to mind is to update the hidden element via JavaScript when the input's value is changed, which this is unnecessary. Is there any way that I can get rid of these hidden elements? or I am not displaying the form control properly. I am not sure.

**UPDATE**

The hidden input elements are added automatically by the razor view itself. Though I am using controllers/views and not razor views, I tested Enrico's solution and the result is the same. It still appends a hidden input element for the checkbox:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually add an hidden input field, or to interact with it via client side Javascript code. The way to go with ASP.NET core and Razor is using the tag helpers and let the actual HTML generation to be done by Razor itself.

This is an example using Razor Pages and a single boolen value in the page input model. I have used ASP.NET core 3.1 and the usual ASP.NET core web application template in Visual Studio 2019.

This is the page model:

```
public class TestFormModel : PageModel
  {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TestFormModel(ILogger<TestFormModel> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
      this.Input = new TestFormModel.InputModel
      {
        ShowUsername = false
      };

      return this.Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost() 
    {
      if (!this.ModelState.IsValid) 
      {
        return this.Page();
      }

      _logger.LogInformation("The posted value is: {Value}", this.Input.ShowUsername);

      return this.RedirectToPage("Index");
    }

    public class InputModel 
    {
      [Display(Name = "Show User Name")]
      public bool ShowUsername { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

This is the associated Razor view:

```
@page
@model StackoverflowTest.Pages.TestFormModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "How to build a form with a checkbox";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<form asp-page="TestForm">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.ShowUsername">
    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="Input.ShowUsername"></label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That's it. You do not need to manually add an hidden input in your form. You just have to use the proper tag helps and ASP.NET core will take care of generating the right form and form inputs for you.

**UPDATE 2 August 2021**

See [this github repository](https://github.com/EnricoMassone/checkbox-form-example) for a working sample.

As a sidenote, please consider that the hidden input field is automatically added by ASP.NET core and it is required in order to post to the server the right value for `Input.ShowUsername` **when the checkbox in the form is unchecked**.

Basically in the generated HTML page source there are **two** form inputs for `Input.ShowUsername`. One of them is an HTML input having `type="checkbox"`, the other one is an HTML input having `type="hidden"`. Both of them have the same value for the `name` attribute (`name="Input.ShowUsername"`), while the `value` attribute is `true` for the checkbox input and `false` for the hidden input.

This is the HTML page source for the form (exactly the way it is generated by ASP.NET core 3.1):

```
<form action="/TestForm" method="post">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Show User Name field is required." id="Input_ShowUsername" name="Input.ShowUsername" value="true">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Input_ShowUsername">Show User Name</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8AHG4SVs1BBFruMHNiza3QNKvHNf96d_oiz5J6n3eYuncnlFKqvL4x3G6jbAOmNfJjrwk_crqFN99kjZiBVoboFGd0VQIBlrvmp9fL6p8CMbiZ4f6Cf4rm3OpGZEZ_04UQQ5iuUi3nVjfIgfb5-vctw" />
  <input name="Input.ShowUsername" type="hidden" value="false">
</form>
```

When the checkbox in the form is checked, the value `true` is posted to the server for the name `Input.ShowUsername`, when the checkbox is unchecked the value `false` is posted to the server for the name `Input.ShowUsername`: **this works because the value of unchecked checkboxes is not posted to the server**.

Adding an input with `type="hidden"` is a common pattern to post a default value for the checkbox when it is unchecked, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) for an explanation about the way HTML checkboxes work.

Again, all of this is automatically generated for you by ASP.NET core: you simply have to define the page input model and to use the proper Razor tag helpers.

Comment: Thank you Enrico. I tested this with a razor page same as your answer. But the hidden elements are still there. I updated my answer with a screenshot of the form HTML output with your answer.

Comment: @mfshujaie that's an implementation detail. I didn't check the generated page source to be honest. Does this solution work for you ? I have tested locally and it is working as I would expect. If the checkbox is checked, then the True value is available in the OnPost method, if the checkbox is not checked the False value is posted. Does this work for you ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When I submit the form the hidden input's value overrides the checkbox's value. I had to remove the `asp-for` from the inputs and populate the name and values myself then it works.

Comment: @mfshujaie have you tried to copy and paste this exact same code in your application ? It seems really strange to me that it doesn't work for you. Are you using ASP.NET core 3.1 ?

Comment: Yes, I copied exactly your code. I am using ASP.NET core 5 btw.

Comment: @mfshujaie I'll push to github my working sample. I'll update the answer with the URL pointing to the working sample, so that you can download it and compare it with your solution.

Comment: @mfshujaie I'll do that today later. Once completed I'll update my answer here.

Comment: @mfshujaie I've updated the answer with a link to a github repo containing the working sample created with Razor pages in ASP.NET core 3.1